# The command "ng serve" works in command prompt but doesn't work vs code for the same project

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I'm new to working with either Angular or visual studio code. I installed node.js and npm which are working fine. The command for running a project `ng serve`, runs perfectly on the command prompt. But, when I switch to the terminal area of the vs code and run the same command `ng serve`, it throws an error as below.

```
ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng serve
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Then again, if I use `npm run ng serve`, it works just like how it should work in vs code terminal.
Is it how it works? If not, what should I do to make it work to just use `ng serve` to run the project?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can **Shift + Right click** in your folder so you can open powershell  and then do `npm install -g @angular/cli` and then generate your project. I think it should work.

Comment: And make sure you open the whole project. Not only src or something like that.

Comment: And one thing, nobody uses cmd prompt.

Comment: I did nothing. But, when I tried `ng serve` on vs code terminal, it worked.
The project is already generated. My issue was with using `ng serve`, which didn't work without the prefix `npm run`.
Thanks for your solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this saves someone headache in the future - I had this exact problem, because I switch terminals a lot and I also switch node versions using nvm when Im dealing with developing on different Angular versions... The reason I kept getting 'command ng not found', was because each version of node that you use has its OWN node_modules global folder, so you need to install angular globally for each node version. My folder structure was $HOME/.nvm/versions/x.x.x/lib/node_modules/@angular

Make sure you install your packages globally for EACH node version you use with nvm!